# Laravel Spatie How to Eager load Role And Permissions at once based on user

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-permission

its possible to eager load role and permissions at once using with()? im doing like code bellow.but not working ,if any of you guys can suggest me an articles or ways to solve this will be helpfull

```
    $user = User::with('roles','permissions')->when(request()->q, function($user) {
        $user = $user->where('name', 'like', '%'. request()->q . '%');
    })->latest()->paginate(20);
```

Comment: `User::with('roles','permissions')` doesnt work? have you tried to `dd` that part only?

Comment: yep , i test it but only the roles come out

Comment: sure the users have permission assigned to them directly?

Comment: the permissions is not assigned to users directly but i assigned it to roles

Comment: if you want to eager load `user`'s `roles` along with `permissions` assigned to `roles`, you will need to `User::with('roles.permissions')`. notice the dot between `roles` and `permission`. this way, when you `dd` the result, it shows the user with roles property and permissions property inside the roles.

Comment: @BagusTesa thx my bro its work

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/244023/discussion-between-shinichirou-ikebe-and-bagus-tesa).

Answer (score 0):

when we are using team=1, we have to use this function before any running query.

```
Route::get('/user-infos',function(){
   setPermissionsTeamId(1);
   $user = User::with('roles')->get();
   return $user;
});
```